# How to show text as a superscript in "Alt text"?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, accessibility

How to show text as a superscript in **Alt text**

**like this:**

Value<sup>10</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like the knittl and SLaKs said, try unicode character html entities.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

```
&#185;&#178;&#179;&#x2074;&#x2075;&#x2076;&#x2077;&#x2078;&#x2079;&#x2070;
```

Result: ¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰

## Bigger: ¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰

Though, for the sake of readability, you might just want to do something like 10^1234.
Or, for citations, whatever[1].

Comment: +1 I agree on the readability comment. I'd be surprised if screen readers could make sense of the alternatives.

Comment: What is the means of this `10^1234`? you mean i should write like this Value^10 and user will understand "10" is superscript.

Comment: @jitendra: Use `value^10` if it means "to-the-10th-power", use something like `value[10]` or `value (see #10)` if it means "see footnote #10". Remember alt-text is used when the image is not available, and should provide semantics not typographical features.

Answer (score 2):

alt text is just normal text, you can try to insert unicode supertext characters:

```
Value¹⁰
```

but it will depend on the font of the viewer (and proper encoding) if it works

Answer (score 2):

You can't; alt text only supports plain text without formatting.

However, you can fake it with Unicode characters. (¹⁰)

Comment: in css font is verdana and i'm using utf 8 charset.